# VBA record will not update with the correct information

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have this simple code that loops through a list box which is attached to a table. It finds the selected items in the list box and updates the corresponding recordset in my "action log" table. My issue is that even though it says `lstAllGroups.Column(1, i)` is holding the correct value; it is not updating the record with that. I've stepped through this in the debugger and it adds everything BUT the groupNum.

```
        Dim recPicker As String
        Dim recAllPicker As String
        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set RstRecSet = db.OpenRecordset("tblActionLog", dbOpenDynaset)
        'Set RstRecSet = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblActionLog Where GroupNum = '" & recAllPicker & "';", dbOpenDynaset)

If chkGrp = True Then

    allGrps = lstAllGroups.ListCount
        For i = 0 To allGrps

            If lstAllGroups.Selected(i) = True Then
            recAllPicker = lstAllGroups.Column(1, i)
                        RstRecSet.AddNew

            RstRecSet("GroupNum").Value = lstAllGroups.Column(1, i)

            RstRecSet("GroupName").Value = lstAllGroups.Column(0, i)

            RstRecSet("ActionItem").Value = txtActionitm.Value

            RstRecSet("GroupNum").Value = recPicker

            RstRecSet("DateClosed").Value = txtDateClosed.Value

            RstRecSet("DateIdentified").Value = txtDateID.Value

            RstRecSet("Analyst").Value = txtAnalyst.Value


            RstRecSet("Comments").Value = txtComments.Value

            RstRecSet.Update
            End If
        Next
Else
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses `lstAllGroups.ListCount` to access the list box rows by index number.  However, `.ListCount` starts counting from 1 and the list box row index values start from 0.  So that means the equivalent of `lstAllGroups.Column(1, lstAllGroups.ListCount)` refers to a row which does not exist in the list box.

Here is an Immediate window example which hopefully clarifies the situation.  My list box contains 4 rows.

```
? Me.lstUsers.ListCount
 4 
? Me.lstUsers.Column(0, 0) ' <-- first row
46
? Me.lstUsers.Column(0, 3) ' <-- last row
48
? Me.lstUsers.Column(0, 4) ' <-- row which does not exist
Null
```

Notice when I ask for a value from a list box row which does not exist, Access just gives me Null without complaint --- it doesn't throw an error message.

I think your code is affected by this issue.  However, I'm unsure whether this is the only factor involved.  It looks to me like your code would add a row to *tblActionLog* with *GroupNum* and *GroupName* values for each row of the list box.  And then add one final row to the table (corresponding to the non-existent list box row) with Null for *GroupNum* and *GroupName*.

Comment: Hey HansUp, Sorry if I was unclear. GroupName gets added with out a problem as well as everything except groupnum. GroupName is the first col in my listbox and GroupNum is the second.

Comment: Still not sure I understand.  Are you saying every row added to *tblActionLog* has Null for *GroupNum*?

Comment: Yeah and I stopped the debugger and it shows lstAllGroups.Column(1, i) is holding the correct value its just not inserting into the record with that value, instead it null. the weird thing is every other one gets updated no problem.

Comment: In that case, does this change anything?: `RstRecSet("GroupNum").Value = Val(lstAllGroups.Column(1, i))`

Comment: Nope it's still showing as null in the db. I debugged it and sure enough RstRecSet("GroupNum").Value = Val(lstAllGroups.Column(1, i)) shows the correct value. stubborn record will not update.

Comment: This is a puzzler.  Can you share a copy of your db?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Working with data that is secret.

Comment: Rats.  Add `DoCmd.SetWarnings True` on the line before `If chkGrp = True Then` and run the code again.  Does that turn up any useful information?

Comment: You know what it was? I'm setting the value of groupnum TWICE LOL. check my code, i'm so scatterbrained. Thanks for your help.